# Wp7 & ReactiveOauth

Tags: windows-phone-7, oauth

I´m having trouble populating a list with the result from an API using ReactiveOauth for wp7.
It works when i´m populating the listbox directly. But I can´t figure out how to add the object to a list instead. The list is always empty when doing it like this .Subscribe(a => lista.Add(new Device ...

Any suggestions is very appreciated.

```
        var token = TelldusWrapper.Security.GetToken();
        var lista = new List<Device>();

        var client = new OAuthClient(ConsumerKey, ConsumerSecret, token)
        {
            Url = "http://api.telldus.com/xml/devices/list",
            Parameters = { { "supportedMethods", "TELLSTICK_TURNON" } }
        };
        client.GetResponseText().Select(s => XElement.Parse(s))
       .SelectMany(x => x.Descendants("device"))
       .Select(x => new
       {
           Text = x.Attribute("id").Value,
           Name = x.Attribute("name").Value
       })
       .ObserveOnDispatcher()
        .Subscribe(a => listbox.Items.Add(new Device { Id = a.Text, Name = a.Name }), ex => MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString())); 
        //.Subscribe(a => lista.Add(new Device { Id = a.Text, Name = a.Name }), ex => MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString()));
```